# Calculus Notation Question

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

What is the difference between $\frac{dy}{dx}$, $\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}$ and $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$? I was reading the derivation of a formula and when I came across this.. as $\Delta x$ approaches zero, $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ approaches $\frac{dy}{dx}$. How can this be explained? And is there a geometrical explanation for this?

Comment: I wonder if you intended $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ rather than $\dfrac{\delta y}{\delta x}\text{ ?}$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I intended to write the 'small change' symbol. Is mine correct?

Comment: when we write δy/δx we want to say δx and  δy is small but not infinite small when we write dy/dx we want to say derivation of y and when we write Δy/Δx we want to say change in y and x and say nothing about their norm. I'm not sure this is true but think that.:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ is a ratio of two physical differences; picture a small but finite right triangle drawn with two acute vertices on the curve $y(x)$.   You can with full rigor work with just $\Delta x$ or $\Delta y$ as an ordinary real number.

$\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}$ is the same thing; but you often would prefer the notation  $\Delta x$ if you are working with actual numerical changes rather than arbitrarily small changes.

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a shorthand for a limit, as  $\Delta x$  goes to zero, of $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.  THe triangle has gotten so small you can't see it anymore.

Although in many circumstances you can manipulate those infinitessimal differences as if they were numbers, they are not -- and you need to be careful when treating them as such.

Answer (score 0):

#### Notation

Authors handle this individually. However often (especially in physics and engineering / applied mathematics) it means

1. Derivative
   $$
   \frac{dy}{dx} = y'(x)
   $$

here $dx$ is a differential.

2. [Functional Derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative)
   $$
   \frac{\delta y}{\delta x}
   $$

used for solving variational problems. $\delta x$ means a [finite variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation) of $x$ with certain boundary conditions like $\delta x(a) = \delta x(b) = 0$ when deriving the Euler-Lagrange equations.

3. Finite Difference

see finite difference equations. $\Delta x$ is a finite value, like $\Delta x = x_{i+1} - x_{i}$.

#### Interpretation

About the approximation question and its geometric interpretation
$$
y'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}
$$
It has the geometrical interpretation of the quotient of the differences in $y$ and $x$, e.g. 
$$
\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{y_{i+1} - y_{i}}{x_{i+1}-x_{i}}
$$
which is the slope of the secant line, to reach the slope of the tangent at the point of interest in the limit case $\Delta x \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is for infinitesimal change.$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ is just a notation for any change like if  you have given two points on a Cartesian plane  (3,4) and (1,2) $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{4-2}{3-1}=\frac{2}{2}=1$.